# Reference an array from values in a cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula which references the row in array in sheet data!G3:R3.

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Expend,Anal,Data!$G$3:$R$3,Budget,INDIRECT("Data!M$"&VLOOKUP(ROW(),CodeMatch,2,FALSE)))

I have the value '3' held in cell H6. I have tried to get the formula to get the value in H6 and put it in as follows: Data!$G$'value in H6':$R$'value in H6'. I am having real trouble working out where the ', ", and & go.

I have tried "Data!$G$"&"H6"&":$R$"&"H6"and all sorts of combinations but get an error each time.

Thanks

Comment: Or use INDEX which is not volatile: `INDEX(Data!G:H,H6,0)`

Comment: Thanks, INDEX works perfectly. I forgot to mention that the value I want is always in column H but on the current row. How do I make H6 be "H"&ROW()" - cos that doesn't work - I am good at stringing functions together but can't get my head round the quotes and ampersand duh.